# Downloading Edited Image

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, download

I'm trying to make an application which has kind a meme generator, I'm wondering,

if I place an image on the screen and I put a textView in there, **is there any way to download that image with the text placed on it?**

Comment: Do you want to upload the edited image in a remote serve or save in a local storage?

Comment: I want to save it in local storage i think, it's just a simple app and I'm a new developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below gitHub library for generating memes

[lucas-meme-generator](https://github.com/ronshapiro/lucas-meme-generator)

Best to use in android-studio but also compitible with eclipse/ant or Intellij/maven if you'd like, but some files/directory hierarchies might be slightly different

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm at school right now, when I'll be at home I will give it a try.

Comment: I don't understand anything from there :)) Maybe you can 'light' my self :)

Comment: use git library mentioned in my answer. it will hepl you to generate meme.

Comment: I know, but I do not understand anything form that code and how should I actually use it? Do you have something where to contact you? I have a simple question about something else.